# mariadb 5.5 innodb keeps opening files up to 200k until system hangs completely

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, mysql, php-fpm

Mariadb 5.5 is installed on CentOS and serves a database in the total volume of around 40GBs (as measured per database files on a disk) and 506 tables. This database is being queried by php-fpm, and the issue is that at some point, when traffic increases, the number of open files opened by `mysqld` process (as per `lsof` states) grows up to around 200k and system hangs (specifically web requests ar being extremely slow, 5mins for TTFB).

The server itself is should have enough capacity (`Supermicro; X10DRH` with 125gb of RAM and SSD) to be able to perform quickly on such a modest load.

Examination of lsof output shows that mysqld process keeps open tables on and where:

`[root@mail proc]# lsof | wc -l
95592`

most of them are open tables:

`[root@mail proc]# lsof | grep .ibd | wc -l
57331`

before that, lsof showed very big qty of /[aio] and putting `innodb_use_native_aio=0` improved the situation a bit

`mysql_slow_log` does not show queries that are running longer than 5s,

`| Innodb_mem_total                         | 33061601280`

my MySQL config is:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_use_native_aio=0
skip-name-resolve=1
max_heap_table_size=256M
tmp_table_size=256M 
slow-query-log=1
long_query_time=1
```

for some tables `mysql.log` shows some errors on startup:

`191205  7:21:25  InnoDB: Error: trying to open a table, but could not
InnoDB: open the tablespace file './staging/yotpo_rich_snippets.ibd'!` but I'm not sure is that might be a reason for low performance.

also, database data files are located in `/home/` partition, which is :

`/dev/md2   /home   ext4    grpquota,usrquota,data=ordered,relatime,rw  0   2`

any hint on where to dig would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like connections are not being closed.  Post 15 seconds of your general log for analysis, please.

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities:

- Some queries are taking a long time (and hanging onto files (that is, tables) meanwhile). --  Look for slow queries; let's work on speeding them up.  You have the slowlog turned on; use `pt-query-digest` to identify the 'worst' queries.
- The APP uses the "EAV" model, which joins lots of tables. --  If this is the case, let's discuss that.
- The web server allows a huge number of connections.  If it is allowing "too many", then will just stumble over each other. "5mins for TTFB" is a clue of this. --  Throttle connections at the web server layer.
- Not effectively using RAM.  You have 125GB of RAM, yet `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is only 1G. --  Change that to 80G.

Meanwhile, delete this Q&A and stick with the better site: dba.stackexchange.com .